Difference of two completely monotonic functions
This question is motivated by the fact that many processes in physics and life sciences can be described by filters $y(t) = [K \ast x](t)$ where $\ast$ denotes convolution and $K(t)$ is a decaying memory kernel on $[0, \infty)$. I am interested to understand whether all continuous functions $K(t)$ that decay to zero at infinity can be represented by sums of decaying exponentials.
We know by the Hausdorff-Bernstein-Widder theorem that any completely monotonic function on the positive half line [0,∞)
is given by the Laplace transform of a positive Borel measure on [0,∞)
, and vice versa. A natural question is how can we characterize the space of functions which are the difference 1−2
of two completely monotonic functions 1,2
. By the same theorem, we know that these functions are equivalent to space of functions which are Laplace transforms of all signed Borel measures. I cannot find any results studying this space and whether, for example, this space of functions can approximate all decreasing functions, all bounded functions, all functions of bounded variation, all functions of a given exponential order, etc.
I'd be really interested to understand how expressive this space is and whether there are any known approximation results of what functions can be approximated by differences of completely monotonic functions.

Why the downvote? This is an interesting and nontrivial question with motivations from applied math and physics.

I don't know whether the following answer is satisfactory or not, but it is too long for a comment. Below I only consider uniform approximations on $[0, +\infty)$.
Let $C_l[0, +\infty)$ denote the space of all continuous functions on $[0, +\infty)$ that have limit as the argument tends to $+\infty$. Endow this space with standard $\sup$-norm. This space is easier to understand as the space of all continuous functions on the one-point compactification of $[0, +\infty)$. I claim that the differences of completely monotonic functions are dense in $C_l[0, +\infty)$.
To prove this note that $L = \mathrm{Span}\{e^{-\alpha t}: \alpha \ge 0\}$ is a subalgebra in $C_l[0, +\infty)$ that separates points and contains non-zero constants. Stone-Weierstrass theorem applied to one-point compactification of $[0, +\infty)$ implies that $L$ is dense in $C_l[0, +\infty)$. Also, $e^{-\alpha t}$ is completely monotonic for $\alpha \ge 0$, so $L$ consists of differences of completely monotonic functions.
Note that if $f$ can be uniformly approximated by differences of completely monotonic functions, then $f \in C_l[0, +\infty)$, since a completely monotonic function is continuous and always has a limit at $\infty$. Thus, $C_l[0, +\infty)$ consists exactly of functions that can be uniformly approximated by differences of completely monotonic functions.

Thank you very much!

Does this in fact imply that every function in [0,+∞) has a well-defined Laplace transform? @Matsmir

No, at least in classical sense. Completely monotonic functions belong to $C^\infty$, so do their differences. I suppose you could define some special sort of test functions and corresponding distributions to define a generalized version of the Laplace transform, but then the Laplace transform also will be a distribution rather than a measure. @GeorgeStepaniants
